# Use Android phone as ARM dev board?

Tags: android, gps, embedded, android-ndk

Is it possible to have a similar peripheral control with Android then we have when making device drivers?

I'm searching for a way to turn off all peripherals on a Android phone (e.g. Display, Wi-Fi, GPS) to put the phone on a power saving mode (1-5 mA).

Basically, I want to develop an application that wake up from time to time, get coordinates, exchange information with a server (Wi-Fi or GSM) and then go to sleep, no need for display.

Is that possible using a regular android phone?

Comment: What you want to do is possible in principle. It needs serious Android hacking skills, but I think it's a much better Idea to buy a linux based ARM dev-board like the BeagleBoard (cheap, and available now) or the Raspberry Pi (incredible cheap and hopefully available soon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only program ARM on Android in User Mode. You don't have access to such instructions as `MRC` in ARM assembly, which require Privileged Modes. Perhaps there are custom ROMs you can install onto your phone to do that, but I doubt it.

This [web site](http://flaviusalecu.com/post/3788777450) has the closest description to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend asking on [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) dev forums, or other such Android hacking sites and see what they have to say. I would not be surprised if the boot loader or something can be convinced to sleep for a long time and then wake the device up on a timer, sort of like an alarm clock.  (I recall some phones used to have this functionality, to wake up on a timer.)